# Can't use Angular Material date range date filter

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, datefilter, angular-daterangepicker

I'm trying to use the new date range picker from Angular Material and I need to filter out some certain days (min and max won't be helpful for me here).
I used before "**matDatepickerFilter**" with the normal date picker but I can't find the same thing for the date range picker so I tried instead using "**dateFilter**".

The problem is that after applying the function I can't select any dates at all.

[Here's a code sample of what I mean (**stackblitz**)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5da2xz)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adapting the `dataFilter` definition for `mat-date-range-input` in the Template should fix your issue.

```
<mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker"  [dateFilter]="rangeFilter">
```

Here is a [working version of your Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5da2xz-ttyiqz).

Comment: the dateFilter only accept 1 date, for date range, it is important to check both dates. doesn't seem to work for us.